# Question about Proof of Cayley-Hamilton:

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading the proof of Cayley-Hamilton from Axler:

Suppose by induction hypothesis that for $1 < j \leq n$

$ 0 = (T-\lambda_1I)v_1 = (T-\lambda_1I)(T-\lambda_2I)v_2 = \ldots = (T-\lambda_1I)\ldots (T-\lambda_{j-1}I)v_{j-1}$

Then since $(T- \lambda_jI)v_j \in$ span$(v_1, \ldots, v_{j-1})$ Then applying $(T-\lambda_1I)\ldots (T-\lambda_{j-1}I)$ to $(T- \lambda_jI)v_j$ gives $0$.

So I try some:

For example:
$Sv_1 = 0$, $(ST)v_2 = 0$, then let $v = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2$

But $(ST)(v) = (ST)(a_1v_1 + a_2v_2) = a_1(ST)v_1$ which is not necessarily $0$? Where is my error?

Comment: Notice that $T-\lambda_i I$ and $T-\lambda_j I$ commute, so your $S$ and $T$ are not arbitrary.  Now you get $(ST)v_1 = T(Sv_1) = 0$.

Comment: ah, missed that, thanks.

Comment: @ErickWong Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 3):

Converting comment to an answer as suggested by Julian in the comments:

If $S$ and $T$ were arbitrary matrices then $(ST)v_1$ might not be zero, but here your $S$ is equal to $T$ plus a scalar, so it commutes with $T$.  It's certainly true that if $S$ and $T$ commute, $(ST)v_1 = T(Sv_1) = 0$.